# Babel no longer accepting JSX after upgrading from webpack 4.0 to 5.0 rails 6.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I'm receiving

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/vw/RubymineProjects/test/app/javascript/packs/home.jsx: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (32:5):
```

I don't know exactly why this is happening, given that I've installed all the required packages for babel to correctly transpile jsx. It was working perfectly fine before I decided to switch over to webpack 5.0. How can I get webpack 5.0 to work with jsx again?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@client-side-validations/client-side-validations": "^0.1.4",
    "@client-side-validations/simple-form": "^0.1.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.14.0",
    "@nathanvda/cocoon": "^1.2.14",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.3-2",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.1.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "6.0.0-pre.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "bloodhound-js": "^1.2.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.2.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.2",
    "emojionearea": "^3.0.0",
    "exports-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "expose-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nouislider": "^14.6.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-color": "^2.18.1",
    "react-datetime": "^3.0.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21",
    "react-input-mask": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "react-player": "^2.6.2",
    "react-widgets": "^5.0.0-beta.21",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "trix": "^1.2.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
  }
}
```

**webpacker.yml**

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: ['app/assets']

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: true

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg
    - .jsx

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  var validEnv = ['development', 'test', 'production']
  var currentEnv = api.env()
  var isDevelopmentEnv = api.env('development')
  var isProductionEnv = api.env('production')
  var isTestEnv = api.env('test')

  if (!validEnv.includes(currentEnv)) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please specify a valid `NODE_ENV` or ' +
        '`BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", ' +
        '"test", and "production". Instead, received: ' +
        JSON.stringify(currentEnv) +
        '.'
    )
  }

  return {
    presets: [
      isTestEnv && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current'
          },
          modules: 'commonjs'
        },
        '@babel/preset-react'
      ],
      (isProductionEnv || isDevelopmentEnv) && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          forceAllTransforms: true,
          useBuiltIns: 'entry',
          corejs: 3,
          modules: false,
          exclude: ['transform-typeof-symbol']
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/preset-react',
        {
          development: isDevelopmentEnv || isTestEnv,
          useBuiltIns: true
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean),
    plugins: [
      'babel-plugin-macros',
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
      isTestEnv && 'babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        {
          loose: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
        {
          useBuiltIns: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        {
          helpers: false,
          regenerator: true,
          corejs: false
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
        {
          async: false
        }
      ],
      isProductionEnv && [
        'babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types',
        {
          removeImport: true
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean)
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `.babelrc`?

Comment: no. It was generated with the install.

Comment: You might need a `.babelrc` I don't know what this error is about, but I know that not having a `.babelrc` has been `90%` of my babel problems

Comment: I didn't have a .babelrc before, and it still compiled. I don't, maybe they changed something with webpack 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing react helped me fix this issue: `bundle exec rails webpacker:install:react`

Comment: had an issue with node js being installed twice.